# Why is RShiny executing code differently than R

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I first noticed graphs graphing differently (different subsets of points on a scatter plot) between Shiny and R. I finally narrowed down my troubleshooting to the data wrangling.  When I run the application file (`repro.R`) below in the Rstudio IDE, I get the following which is incorrect.

[image]

When I run the code inline, and replace the `input$...` with hard values that represent what the application is passing, I get different results and they are correct.

[image]

I've posted this on the RStudio community page as well, but no answers yet. Insight is much appreciated!

I've place `testdata.RData` and the R-Shiny script `repro.R` on `https://github.com/jshousephd/repro.test`.

Inline code here:

```
library(tidyverse)
testdata %>%
dplyr::filter(trt == trt_list[2]) %>%
dplyr::select(x = log2FoldChange, qx = padj, mylabel) -> x
testdata %>%
dplyr::filter(trt == trt_list[1]) %>%
dplyr::select(y = log2FoldChange, qy = padj, mylabel) -> y
plotdata <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, by = c("mylabel"))
plotdata %>% dplyr::mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x),
y = ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y),
qx = ifelse(is.na(qx), 1, qx),
qy = ifelse(is.na(qy), 1, qy)) %>%
dplyr::mutate(significance = ifelse(plotdata$qx <= .1 & plotdata$qy > .1, "X-Significant",
ifelse(plotdata$qx > .1 & plotdata$qy <= .1, "Y-Significant",
ifelse(plotdata$qx <= .1 & plotdata$qy <= .1, "Both-Significant", "Neither")))) %>%
dplyr::filter(significance != "Neither") -> plotdata
final <- as.data.frame(table(plotdata$significance))
final
```

Session

```
    sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] shinythemes_1.1.2 DT_0.5 forcats_0.4.0 stringr_1.4.0 dplyr_0.8.0.1 purrr_0.3.2 readr_1.3.1 tidyr_0.8.3 tibble_2.1.1
[10] ggplot2_3.1.1 tidyverse_1.2.1 shiny_1.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.1 cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1 compiler_3.6.0 later_0.8.0 plyr_1.8.4 tools_3.6.0 digest_0.6.18 lubridate_1.7.4
[10] jsonlite_1.6 nlme_3.1-139 gtable_0.3.0 lattice_0.20-38 pkgconfig_2.0.2 rlang_0.3.1 cli_1.1.0 rstudioapi_0.10 crosstalk_1.0.0
[19] yaml_2.2.0 haven_2.1.0 withr_2.1.2 xml2_1.2.0 httr_1.4.0 htmlwidgets_1.3 hms_0.4.2 generics_0.0.2 grid_3.6.0
[28] tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.0 R6_2.3.0 readxl_1.3.1 modelr_0.1.4 magrittr_1.5 backports_1.1.4 scales_1.0.0 promises_1.0.1
[37] htmltools_0.3.6 rvest_0.3.3 assertthat_0.2.1 mime_0.6 xtable_1.8-3 colorspace_1.4-1 httpuv_1.4.5.1 stringi_1.2.4 lazyeval_0.2.2
[46] munsell_0.5.0 broom_0.5.2 crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: It's *really* preferable if you can just post a representative sample of the data in the question with the minimal amount of code needed to help debug the issue.

Comment: @camille I agree with you. While the data might be a little over the top, it appears to be necessary, as random number generation did not replicate the issue.  As far as code, I did exactly that.  The minimal amount of code is here....  The inline code and the Shiny application code are necessary to replicate the issue. I'm sorry it requires downloading two files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `input$adj.pvalue` is being returned as a character, not a number. Rather than using that value directly, use `as.numeric(input$adj.pvalue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that the values of `selectInput` are stored as **characters**, so you have to convert them to **numeric** like: `padj <- as.numeric(input$adj.pvalue)`

Then replace `input$adj.pvalue` with `padj`, and you get the desired result:

```
dplyr::mutate(significance = ifelse(plotdata$qx <= padj & plotdata$qy > padj, "X-Significant",
                                          ifelse(plotdata$qx > padj & plotdata$qy <= padj, "Y-Significant",
                                                 ifelse(plotdata$qx <= padj & plotdata$qy <= padj, "Both-Significant", "Neither")))) %>%
      dplyr::filter(significance != "Neither") -> plotdata
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!